# Связь компонентов и доступ к data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Как связать компоненты и получить доступ к data.
В проекте использую vue-route. Структура такая

> component
>
> > a.vue
> >
> > b.vue
> >
> > c.vue
>
> app.vue
>
> main.js

использую es6 для связывания

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import app from './app.vue'
```

`app.vue` получает данные к которым необходимо иметь доступ в других компонентах. Согласно документации доступ к ним нужно получать через `props`
Что я и пытаюсь сделать.
Компонент `app.vue` отображает часть шаблона и получает данные.
Компонент `a.vue` доступен по route `'/'`
Подключаю компонент `app.vue` к `a.vue` что бы получить доступ к его `data`.

```
import app from './../app.vue';
export default {
    component: {
        app
    },
    props: ['item', 'settings']
}
```

Но в `props` у меня `undefined`. В `app.vue` данные приходят и там в `data` все на месте. У меня подозрение что я не правильно связывают компоненты, и `a.vue` не знает откуда брать данные.

p.s надеюсь смог доступно изложить суть проблемы.

Comment: Может быть вам подойдёт использование Vuex? Документация https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/intro.html

Comment: Апп тут новый инстанс поэтому и пропсов нет.

Answer (score 0):

В `es6` почему-то обычный подход получения `props` не работает. Я сталкивался с этой проблемой, к сожалению, ничего лучше передачи данных напрямую в компонент я не нашел. Пример передачи

```
<router-view :item="item" :settings="settings"></router-view>
```

Делать `import app.vue` и `a.vue` в этом случае нет необходимости, router уже их подключил. Подобные вопросы и ответы лучше искать на официальном форуме `vue js`. Если найдете решение обычным подходом или любым другим, напишите его, а то надоедает передавать в шаблон.